# Using Spring have multiple JSON request (POST) in a single HTTP call

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

How can I use Spring3 framework when combining 2 different REST (using JSON) requests within a single HTTP call? I am using Spring with jackson for JSON conversion. What is the most optimal way of doing it? I am not sure, if it comes under multi-part request.

For example, if I had the following 2 unrelated JSON payloads that I want to combine in a single HTTP call.

```
"json1": 
{ 
"Name": "abc", 
"Age": "111" 
} 

"json2": 
{ 
"stockName": "xyz", 
"stockSymbol": "SS" 
}
```

Once my main controller method handles the initial call, is it then possible to map different additional controller methods for different JSON payloads? I want to understand what is the optimal way of handling such scenarios?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate resources and call separately, that is the best approach. In the calling place you can combine both JSON output. Right now you are trying like to have a method with two different different return types